# Write on the same line in TextEdit in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

When we use `ui->TextEdit->append("...")` the text entered will be shown in a new line in the TextEdit section. What I want to do is to write on the same line... I've tried this code:

```
ui->textEdit->append("My name is:");
ui->textEdit->append("\b bla");
```

but it seems that "\b" isn't recognised by Qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an option is to do the append outside of the QTextEdit to avoid having a new paragraph created:

```
QString text = ui->textEdit->text();
text.append("bla");
ui->textEdit->setText(text);
```